# Minimum requirements for two-handing weapons in DS3

Tags: dark-souls-3

So I am looking to optimize a build in Dark Souls 3, and I have been looking for the minimum requirements for certain weapons when using two hands. However, the wiki pages all simply report the base stats to use it with one hand. For example, the Carthus Curved Greatsword requires 18 Str, and 22 Dex.

If I attempt to use this with lower than the minimum required stats, I cannot effectively wield it one-handed, but I do know that I can wield it effectively, two-handed. My issue though is knowing exactly what the ratio is for the *bare* minimum, to wield a weapon two-handed. For example, is it 2/3? Does the requirement have to only be in one (e.g str), or all required stats? Does this also work differently for weapons that require a Faith or Intelligence base level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-handing gives you a 1.5x multiplier on your STR for the purpose of both STR scaling and meeting requirements, rounded down.

If you have a weapon that requires 11 STR, you will need only 8 STR to Two-hand it, since 7 gives you 10.5 and that is rounded down to 10.

[Source](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Strength)